# my eclipse splits editor windows automatically, it's extremely annoying for me.

Tags: eclipse, split

Does anybody know how to disable this auto-splitting?

"
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
"

Answer (score 0):

Please see the image Windows==>Editor==>Toggle split Editor.

[image]

Comment: I didn't ask how to split windows. I asked how to disable automatic splitting.